# Get content id (greatest) by clicking button on it Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get comment id when clicking to report button (I want to get comment-6)
Now when I click 'report' it show a modal box with form.

```
    <div class="comment-box medium-comment" id="comment-6">
        <div class="photo-box">
        <img src="img/samples/photo_1.jpg" alt="" class="photo rounded"/>
        <a href="#" title="" class="corner rounded"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="avatars">
        <a href="#" title="">
            <img src="img/samples/followers/1.jpg" alt=""/>dearskye
        </a>
        <span>commented on</span>
        <a href="#" title="">
            <img src="img/samples/followers/2.jpg" alt=""/>Antony12
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="comment rounded">
        <div class="bg-tl"></div>
        <div class="text">Happy golden days of yore
                  Happy golden days of yore Happy golden days 
             of yore</div>
        <div class="buttons">
           <a href="#" title="" class="report">REPORT</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cinfo">
        2 дня назад
        </div>
        <div class="both"></div>
    </div>
```

clicking to

```
<a href="#" title="" class="report">REPORT</a>
```

call jquery

```
jQuery('a.report').bind('click', function(event) {
    showModalWindow('report-window');
});
```

and function is

```
function checkReportForm(form)
{
var result=true;
var select=jQuery("#report-window select");
var textarea=jQuery("#report-window textarea");

if(textarea.hasClass('default'))
{
    //Save placeholder
    textarea.data('placeholder', textarea.text());
    textarea.toggleClass('default');
}
textarea.attr('class','rounded');

if(select.val()==0)
{
if(textarea.val()==''||textarea.val()==textarea.data('placeholder'))
{
    result=false;
    textarea.toggleClass("alert");
}
}
if(result)
{
closeModalWindow('report-window');
}
```

I tried to do it but nothing. I suppose it is possible otherwise will think to change code. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: What is not working? You need to get the comment id into the modal dialog?

Comment: yes! only comment id in what I link report button.  On my html page I have 10 comments and each have own individual id. Every comment have structure like this (like example comment id-6)

Comment: I do not see where "checkReportForm" is called? Also, I tried your code, commenting out the showModalWIndow and the click event was called properly. Does your click event fire?

Comment: I have add my form and a button which call checkReportForm. I try to add data to mysql but I need to know sending report to which comment it belongs so that I need to know comment id. I do not know how to call comment id from checkReportForm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest` to get the closest element which cotains the required class and get its id. Try this.

```
jQuery('a.report').click(function() {
    var $commentBox = $(this).closest(".comment-box");
    var id = $commentBox.attr('id').replace('comment-', '');
    alert(id);//It will alert the comment id

    //Store the comment id in report window
    $('#report-window').data('commentid', id);
});
```

Now use `$('#report-window').data('commentid')` to get the current comment id inside `checkReportForm` method.

Comment: I use $.noConflict(); and call everything with jQuery instead of $ i tried to modify the code but do not get it to work. Can you please show an example with jQuery instead of $('').clic...

Comment: I have add your code to my jquery call     jQuery('a.report').bind('click', function(event) {
 
    var $commentBox = $(this).closest(".comment-box");
    alert($commentBox.attr('id').replace('comment-', ''));
    
    showModalWindow('report-window');
    
    
    
    });

Comment: and now when I click report it show a curent id ! It start working ! but my goal is to show alert whecn I click send from my report form. So 1) I click report from comment 2) opens report form and when I send it I get comment id. How can I get it from function checkReportForm? I tried to put the smae code , do not work (

Comment: I edited my topic. I post below how looks my jquery form call now. clicking report it every time in alert show current id but when I try to add alert(jQuery('#report-window').data('commentid', id)); it start not working, form not shut down and closeModalWindow('report-window'); do not call . When I delete id alert(jQuery('#report-window').data('commentid')); it works and show in alert "undefined" ...

Comment: ` alert(jQuery('#report-window').data('commentid', id));` will alerty an object because you are assigning value to commentid data attribute. Use this ` alert(jQuery('#report-window').data('commentid'));` if you want to see the commentid.

Comment: alert(jQuery('#report-window').data('commentid'));

Comment: still get alert with text "undefined" tried to add .text() nothing work. Using your aler it show "undefined" text in alert (not id) but comment box close ok, so here is not error. Any ideas ?

Comment: please look at "My function now looks :" at first post I edited it

Comment: You have missed this line form my answer `//Store the comment id in report window
    $('#report-window').data('commentid', id);`. See carefully my answer, that line set the commentid. Since you missed it so you are getting it as `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you very much I read everything once more and find where is problem. Now it works ! Many thank's to you !

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, the following should fetch the comment id for you:

```
$(".report").click(function() {
    var $box = $(this).parents(".comment-box");
    var commentId = $box.attr("id").replace("comment-", "");

    // commentId contains 6
    // call showModalBox and do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: thank you can you please help me to add your code to function. I want to get id from function. I use $.noConflict(); and call everything with jQuery

Comment: I edit my topic. Please look at html part. I post a full form which is called (show) when click  <a href="#" title="" class="report">REPORT</a>

Comment: No, what you are showing is that you call showModalWindow when `a.report` is clicked (in your third snippet).

Answer (score 0):

When `this` context is your report link:

```
var id = Number(this.parentNode.parentNode.id.substring(8));
```